# Python module to measure objects in SVG file?

Tags: python, svg, xml-parsing, vector-graphics

I have a bunch of SVG files, each containing a collection of polylines that I want to measure the lengths of. This is one typical polyline:

```
<path d="M 1828.0 1476.0 1838.0 1384.0 1771.0 1360.0 1730.0 1334.0 1687.0 1344.0 1654.0 1352.0 " stroke="rgb(255,200,0)" fill="none" stroke-width="8.0"/>
```

In each SVG are a couple hundred of these lines.

Are there Python SVG handling modules that can process this and measure the lengths? If they don't exist, are there existing solutions for parsing SVG files so I only need to develop something for measuring (and not parsing)? If there are such modules, I would appreciate any tips on how to approach this problem. I don't have a strong preference for Python 2 or 3, though I am new to Python and most of what I've done is in Python 2.

Thank you very much!

P.S. I have found [svgwrite](http://packages.python.org/svgwrite/) and [pysvg](http://codeboje.de/pysvg/), but looks like they both write SVG files and don't really parse them or do any measurements.

Comment: The inkscape application is largely written in Python. It contains modules for working with SVG that may be used independently. You might check out the source code to that.

Comment: You can use PyQt SVG module to read and write svg files.Also, I've used SVGfig library ([link](https://code.google.com/p/svgfig/)), I find it better implemented and easier to use.